# Using a macro in QRcode

Tags: macros, qrcode

I want to define a macro, \pfad, which i would like to use in \qrcode.
It is not throwing errors at me, hurray, but isn't working perfectly. It includes a %20 in the url.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{qrcode}\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\pfad}{http://qr.bleistiftundlineal.de/}
\begin{document}
\pfad L8331.pdf
\qrcode{\pfad L8331.pdf}
\end{document}
```

How do i get rid of that?

Comment: Rework definition and "call": https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros

Comment: Remove the trailing slash in `\pfad` and input `\qrcode{\pfad/L8331.pdf}`

Comment: That worked also. Thank you for teaching me new stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution seems to be to define `\pfad` to take an argument:

[image: Sample output with mouseover]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\pfad}[1]{http://qr.bleistiftundlineal.de/#1}

\begin{document}

\pfad{L8331.pdf}

\qrcode{\pfad{L8331.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: HA, i am so sure i tried that in the beginning. But, apparently not in the right way. Thanks

Comment: I like very much your solution.